# Fast way to make multiple AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i have a web application which is making around 14-15 AJAX calls to some APIs. The problem is the amount of time all the AJAX calls takes is nearly 3x than the time in which each individual API shows me response when I type its URL in the browser.

I am making all the AJAX calls instantly inside the DOM Ready event.

The thing is how can i speed up this process of making 15 AJAX calls together, getting the response as fast as possible and Manipulating the DOM accordingly.

Few Points which i have in my mind:

1. All the AJAX calls should be ASYNC in nature. (Already doing it).
2. Don't make all the AJAX calls at the same time. Induce some sort of timeout as making all the AJAX calls at the same time may block the bandwidth and slows down the turn around time of the process.
3. Reducing the number of API calls by any means. (Already doing it).
4. Manipulate the DOM as minimal as possible. (Already doing it).
5. Setting `cache:true` in AJAX setup. I don't think that will really help, still i am doing it wherever i am sure content will update really slow.

Any suggestions will be valuable! Thanks.

**The way i am making AJAX calls**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    loadSentimentModule();
    loadCountModule();
    loadEntitiesModule();  
    // Some more function calls.

});

function loadSentimentModule(){

   $.ajax({
          url:someurl,
          cache:true,
          dataType:"json",
          success: function(data){

              // Based on data manipulating DOM.
          }

}

// Same kind of function defintions for all the functions.
```

Comment: Show your way of doing multiple Ajax Requests..

Comment: @user1354678 typed in. Please check

Comment: `Reducing the number of API calls by any means` Sure that's where you should start. If you can handlle all data just by making one ajax request, then you're a winner :)

Comment: If you have control over the API server, you could regroup all these calls into one or two calls.

Comment: @A.Wolff but can't do that. Say every API call has its own function. I can't club them. Will setting a timeout will work?

Comment: @ShanShan no i can't do that.. I dont have access to API server.

Comment: @void I was guessing you have control over the API methods. Are you sure there isn't one mehtod handling all this for you? You could still send one request to your own server which will handle all requests to the API for you, could be other solution but that's depends if there is some specific limitation regarding this API usage

Comment: @A.Wolff On DOM ready i call a single function which call 14 other functions which have the AJAX calls.

Comment: @void No, i'm not talking about doing all the requests client side, but server side, if possible

Comment: Do you have a server running? You could use the same idea. Your client issues one request (with an array of api_to_call/params?) to your server and your serve would do all the API calls and returns one huge array of data. It's lighter for the client and you'd have consistent performance and response time

Comment: @ShanShan Ya exactly what i was thinking, and by the way, would be easier to handle some cache logic server side

Comment: @A.Wolff ShanShan just imagine 7 calls takes around 1s and rest 7 takes 10s, now if i club them either on client or ons server then the response time will increase like anything. Even the calls which takes a second to load will start taking more time.

Comment: Can you guess what must be causing the issue. I am loading the webpage on a really fast internet connection.

Comment: @void question is now quite interesting and now i am eager to watch that perfect answer :D.

Comment: @void Imagine your server do all requests API to get data one time per hour, store it, cache it, whatever. Then your user**s** will request your server to get all these datas using only one request

Comment: @A.Wolff so you are saying to store the response of all calls  at some middle layer then i can fetch from there without any delay?

Comment: @void I said, if possible, minus to the maximum ajax call client side. And ya, if possible, use your server to proxify all these datas coming from third party API. That's what i would try to start with. BUT some APIs have some restrictions, without knowing which API you are talking about, I don't know. BTW, this suppose all these datas are public, not private regarding specific user

Comment: The current browsers have neat ways to visualize all request, the duration, and dom events. Does that show anything to help you  see whether
* The requests are issued in parallel?
* Any delays occur?

Comment: @A.Wolff No i can't do that, the query Params i am using to build the URL for API call is really dynamic and can have 1000s of possible perumtations and combinations.

Comment: @void So ya, unfortunately that's not possible :(

Answer (score 4):

You may not issue the ajax call directly, but queue them and let a manager control the queue, see here: [Queue ajax requests using jQuery.queue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785724/queue-ajax-requests-using-jquery-queue)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't knew about it. But how does it makes things faster?

Comment: Doing things in a sequence on limited resources is always faster than in parallel. The limited resource over here is the bandwidth, as you already stated in your OP, and probably also the browser which needs to handle all the XML requests

Comment: Bandwidth i don't this is a issue. But say a call takes 10s, then if i will make 10 of these kind of calls in series then they will take atleast 100s (without caching enabled) and if i will 10 of these in parallel the time will be really less. What say?

Comment: @void Cannot you make only one relevant ajax call regarding some specif user interaction? Said e.g, user click button `loadSentimentModule`, call `loadSentimentModule()`, etc... ? Because if the issue comes from slow API and you cannot cache it in some way, i don't think there is really any solution to this issue

Comment: @A.Wolff the thing is, When i am making an individual API call it takes 1s and when i make 10s of calls the call which was taking 1s starts taking 5s or so. I think there should be wayaround for this

Comment: @void A browser is limited regarding number of parallele requests done at same time. You could try calling a max of 2/3 requests in parallel maybe with some kind of logic.

Comment: @void EDIT: seems the best way is still to let browser handling it, which seems logic afterall: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276784/jquery-limit-the-number-of-simultaneous-ajax-requests   My idea was something like that (kind of pseudo code not tested): http://jsfiddle.net/8rp4yacp/1

Comment: 10+ AJAX requests in one go seems an architecture issue. 2-3 is fine I think, but 10 of those and each taking 10 seconds is a tremendous overhead and you should definitively consider combining those in to something larger

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use the [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) module on client. May be it this what are you looking for.

Comment: What does it do? And how it will be faster if i am making parallel AJAX calls?

Comment: Is it really diffrent than using promise/deferred queue logic?