# Ajax & JavaScript | Limiting requests triggered by user

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am currently playing around with some Ajax code. I have come up with this scenario to try and mirror my problem to see if you, experts, can present a solution, thanks.

**Scenario:**

I have a HTML button like so: `<p onclick="ajax_call();">Click</p>`. Upon clicking this button it will launch an AJAX request to a php page like this:

```
function ajax_launch(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = ajax_launch_callback;

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/php_script", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function ajax_launch_callback(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        // code to do something once response is here successfulyl 
    }
}
```

This then does some PHP code in the `php_script` file and returns an `$output`

**Issue:**

The `php_script` page that is called via AJAX is quiet heavy and makes several API and database calls making the page "slow" to load (which is perfectly fine). However at the moment, whilst the page is waiting for a response (it is still doing the php and not yet returned anything) a user can technically spam the button to launch many ajax calls. Ideally, this will just produce stress on the server and I need a way that once the request is pending and not come back, you cannot make further requests.

How can i achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance, looking forward for your solutions/consultation

**ALSO:**

By multiple requests, this is what i mean - see picture of when i spam click the button to launch several requests whilst the first one isn't done (not returned anything yet):

[Image of chrome debugger (networks tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhlNl.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276784/jquery-limit-the-number-of-simultaneous-ajax-requests   . CHECK LAST TWO ANSWERS

Comment: Mask  the button with a loading icon while request is in progress. Lets users know something is happening

Comment: I believe the best way to do that is to do a check in php let's say a session!

Answer (score 2):

Although the mentioned javascript solutions here and in the linked question are a nice addition, you should really do this server-side as a spammer would not necessarily be using a browser and / or could have javascript disabled.

If you use sessions on the server, the session will be locked when a request is being processed so you will only process one request per user at a time. However, requests could queue up (that is perhaps what is showing in your networks tab data?) so you could complement that with a rate limit on for example the IP address.

Comment: Can you explain this rate limit? Exactly as you said, there will still be requests being made as shown in my networks tab, is this not a problem? way i see it, its an extra ajax call.

Comment: @FlyingPheonix For example you can get the visitors ip address, log it in a database with a timestamp and before you continue check how many entries already exist from the last xx seconds or minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var xmlhttp;
function ajax_launch() {
    if (xmlhttp && xmlhttp.readyState == 4 || !xmlhttp) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = ajax_launch_callback;

        xmlhttp.open("POST", "/php_script", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

function ajax_launch_callback() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        // code to do something once response is here successfulyl 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's going to throw a reference error since you are trying to read from xmlhttp before you declare it.

Comment: @Quentin added declaration, I've assumed it was there in the code that was not post.

Comment: But since that is JS, the user can just change it or create his own js calls, right?

Comment: @FlyingPheonix — Well yes, or HTTP requests without using JS at all, but the way your question was phased implied you wanted to solve the problem of "User gets bored of waiting and clicks again" rather than "Malicious users sends as many requests as they can"

Comment: @Quentin doesnt matter for users intentions, its the effects on my server.

Answer (score 0):

This things might be helpful:

**Add this HTML**

```
<div style="display: none;" id="screenblocker">&nbsp;</div>
```

**And this styles:**

```
#screenblocker {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    z-index:9999999;
}
```

**And script part:After the AJAX call**

```
    var e = document.getElementById('screenblocker');
    if (e != null) {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('screenblocker').style.display = 'none';", 5000);//considering 5 seconds to load, you can block longer if needed
    }
```

**And on AJAX success:**

```
document.getElementById('screenblocker').style.display = 'none';
```